# Slack integration goes to 404 from Meta Stack Overflow user profile settings

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, slack

Slack integration settings for teams is shown correctly in the Stack Overflow main user profile settings.

However, in my Meta Stack Overflow user profile,

[image]

It goes to page not found with the URL `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/integrations/slack/<id>`.

[image]

It should either show the same as the main user profile or the integration setting shouldn't be shown for meta user if it is not applicable.

Comment: Is [meta-tag:stackoverflow-for-teams] related to [meta-tag:slack] integration?

Comment: @msanford yeah, the Slack integration is a feature of Teams.

Comment: Still happening today.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out! This is a bug and we’ve pushed a fix.

There is no Slack integration (yet) for anything but Stack Overflow for Teams, therefore that setting should not have been exposed on your profile, outside of your Teams settings.

You should no longer be seeing the Slack option in that context, but let me know if the problem persists. Thanks again for the report!

Comment: Possibly related, but our new Team's default questions includes one with a Too Many Redirects error for Slack Integration: https://stackoverflow.com/users/integrations/slack/current

Comment: @AlienLifeForm thanks for the report - I'm able to repro this one and will pass it on to the team.

Comment: Great thanks. Got slack integration working via Settings > General Settings > Slack once I found it