# Dead links in settings

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, stack-overflow-for-teams, 404-not-found

I found some dead links in my settings:

[image: Settings Page]

https://stackoverflow.com/users/integrations/slack/current

https://stackoverflow.com/users/integrations/microsoft-teams/current

Both of these links redirect to a 404 page
[image]

It seems like this may have unintentionally been shown as this is a previous answer:

[Slack integration goes to 404 from Meta Stack Overflow user profile settings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365459/slack-integration-goes-to-404-from-meta-stack-overflow-user-profile-settings)

Comment: Those settings are related to SO for Teams and it's working correctly for those who have Teams. Are you not on any Teams?

Comment: If this does 404 for everyone not on a team. It probably should either not render the settings if you're not in any teams or show an empty list with some "About Teams" text ( [this kinda thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXh1u.png) )

Comment: I am not in a team - no.

Comment: It's [status-planned on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379806/323179)